# Application of MVT on the example of population of squirrels.

Tags: calculus

The growth of a population of squirrels at time $t$ (months) is given by the function

$$y(t) = 1000\cdot\left(4 + t −\frac{12}{\pi}\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{6}\right)\right).$$

Using the intermediate value theorem show that $|y(b)−y(a)| \leq 3000\cdot |b−a|$, without loss of generality you can assume $b>a$.

MVT: $$|y(b) - y(a)|/(b - a) = y'(c)$$

I have found that

$$y'(t) = 1000(2\cdot \sin(\frac{\pi t}{6}) + 1).$$

And that the critical points (where $y'(t) = 0$) is when $t = 7$ and $t = 11$. And that $y(t)$ is increasing when $t$ is in the interval $[12n, 7 + 12n)\cup(11 + 12n, 12 + 12n]$ and decreasing when $t$ is in the interval $(7 + 12n, 11 + 12n)$. But I have trouble tying this up to the fact that $-1 \leq \sin(\frac{\pi c}{6}) \leq 1$, and when I tried proving by contradiction I didn't get how I could do it, because the critical points yielded $y(11) > 3000$, so I didnt get a contradiction.

Comment: The population of squirrels can have irrational number of squirrels? How do you achieve that?

Comment: You can think of it as a curve that approximates the average growth of squirrels @JCAA

Comment: Are you confusing the intermediate value theorem with the mean value theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $y'(t)=1000\left(2\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}6\right)+1\right)$ and since $\left|2\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}6\right)\right|\leqslant2$, you have\begin{align}|y'(t)|&=\left|1000\left(2\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}6\right)+1\right)\right|\\&\leqslant1000\times(2+1)\\&=3000.\end{align}Therefore,$$\frac{|y(b)-y(a)|}{b-a}\leqslant3000.$$

Comment: If I were OP, this wouldn't of have explained much to me. Especially his mistakes like the wrong usage of IVT.